# install MySQL or any other lite weight database?

Tags: applications

I have a android mobile with version 4.1 Installed. for my practices I am thinking that  it would be nice if I have a database in that.

If it is MySQL I would love that. could somebody tell me how can I install MySQL in android ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Android comes with SQLite. That should be adequate for most applications.

Comment: can u setup replication to an online mysql server when the device gets internet connection it copies the whole local SQLite db to an online mysql db?

Answer (score 2):

There are some packages on *Google Play* you might wish to check:

- [Bit Web Server (PHP,MySQL,PMA)](http://www.appbrain.com/app/Bit-Web-Server-PHP-MySQL-PMA/com.andi.serverweb)
- [Ulti Server: PHP, MySQL, PMA](http://www.appbrain.com/app/Ulti-Server-PHP-MySQL-PMA/com.icecoldapps.ultiserver)
- [KSWEB: server + PHP + MySQL](http://www.appbrain.com/app/KSWEB-server-PHP-MySQL/ru.kslabs.ksweb)

As the names suggest, all these are web servers bundled with *MySQL* and some scripting support (PHP). A [search for mysql](http://www.appbrain.com/search?q=mysql) might reveal additional candidates.

Answer (score 0):

- Bit Web Server, Ulti Servers, and ksweb is not free
- Palapa Web Server is free but I can not connect to their Mysql Server on Android x86 CPU.

Well, there is a Free and very lite [Mysql Server for Android](http://solusiprogram.com/mysql-server-android/) that support all cpus (armv6, armv7, armv8/aarch64, and x86).

Comment: What is your connection to this product? You seem to have responded similarly to recommend this product multiple times today.

Comment: I commented you at https://android.stackexchange.com/a/173659/218252