# How can I install MySQL on my Android device(s)?

Tags: applications, installation, internet, offline, app-data

There are good and bad choices available for the design of my system and MySQL seems to be the best available.  I need it to run client/server and support stored procedures & triggers and a host of other features.  But I also need a database that will run single-user on mobile devices when off-line, then synchronize with the on-line server when reconnected to the Internet.  The only database provided with Android is SQLite - which doesn't even come close to providing the features required.  Also, installing MySQL on Android devices would mean that I wouldn't have to support any incompatibilities between two different databases.  I do not need other features installed (HTML server, PHP, etc)... just MySQL.  How can I get that installed (and with my apps(s)) and have it work easily and efficiently (and not have to root or install a new ROM on the device)?

Comment: This answer should answer you: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/61056/install-mysql-or-any-other-lite-weight-database/173658#173658

Answer (score 2):

A [search for "mysql"](http://www.appbrain.com/search?q=mysql) on the stores can answer this: there are several packages available, usually together with a web server and PHP. Best candidates are probably [AndroPHP](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ayansoft.androphp) and [Palapa](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.alfanla.android.pws).

My list of [web servers with scripting support](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists.php?topic=cat;id=113#group_414) also have some of them (e.g. the two I mentioned), together with links to reviews, video demos, etc – which might make your decision easier.

Answer (score 0):

This is a Free and very lite [Mysql Server for Android](http://solusiprogram.com/mysql-server-android/) that

- support all cpus (armv6, armv7, armv8/aarch64, and x86).
- no root needed
- support Innodb

Comment: What is your connection to this product? You seem to have responded similarly to recommend this product multiple times today.

Comment: yes, I recommended it TWO times for different questions which haven't set as duplicated. I would like to give only a link to my first answer, but it will only show as a comment that people may miss.